# How do I pass dirname to filename for multiple files in multiple directories?

Tags: bash, variables, awk, dirname

I have multiple test directories with very specific names, and within those directories I have multiple sub directories with multiple sub directories.

Example:

*./V01A1A01/S01/R00/JADE/Anytest.drec
*./V01A1A01/S01/R01/JADE/Anytest.drec (note sub dir R01 is different)

etc...

*./V01A1A01/S02/R00/JADE/Anytest.drec
*./V01A1A01/S02/R01/JADE/Anytest.drec (note S02 and sub dir R01 are now different)

etc...

I want to replace and rename the `Anytest.drec` in all directories with a source file "Anytext.drec" (path=/home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/Source_Files/Anytest.drec) that I change from time to time. I want the final name in the /JADE directory to take on the dirname so that Anytest.drec now reads = V01_A1_A01_S01_R00.drec.

Here's my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash 

path1=/home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/Source_Files/Anytest.drec  #set path of source Anytest.drec file
set -x  #allows me to see what things are going on with code
echo "Please enter the Master folder you wish to search or update"   #asks user for the input folder to search
read "folder"       #creates variable "$folder" and sets the directory I want to search
jade_files=`find /home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/$folder -name "*.drec" -print`

#finds all filenames in var $folder with the extension of .drec and puts the result in var $jade_files which now = /home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/V01A1A02/S00/R00/JADE/Anytest.drec
path=`dirname "$jade_files"`  #dirname gives full paths of .drec files and puts result into var $path 
ext=${jade_files##*.}       #uses the var $jade_file to get the extension of .drec files found in the find search which = drec
basename=`basename "$jade_files"`  #gets the basenames from var $file which = Anytest.drec

#here's where my problems start... I'm trying to use the content of var "$jade_folders" to cp /Source_Files/Anytest.drec into var "$jade_folders" path(s) and using awk to parse out the portion of the dirname want to reconfigure into the filename
while read -r line; do   
    new_name=| `awk '{print $5, "_", $6, "_", $7 }'`
    echo $new_name
    cp -b /home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/Source_Files/"$new_name"."$ext" "$line"
done <<< "$jade_folders"  #essentially, this var is the input to the while loop and <<< is how it's done.
```

What I get out is this:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/Source_Files/.drec’: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this script to make it do what I want?

okay, this is the fix i ended up using, it doesn't put all the underscores but it puts in most.  I'll fix the rest as I learn more.  Thanks Ed:

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    path1=/home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/Source_Files/Anytest.drec
    set -x
    echo "Please enter the Master folder you wish to search or update"
    read "folder"
    jade_files=`find /home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/$folder -name "*.drec" -print`
    path=`dirname "$jade_files"`
    ext=${jade_files##*.}
    basename=`basename "$jade_files"` 
    cp -b "$path1" "$jade_files"."$ext"
```

Comment: What is the intent of the line `new_name=| \`awk '{print $5, "_", $6, "_", $7 }'\``? How is `path1` intended to be used? Why are you using the words `folder` and `directory` - do you intend them to mean the same thing (UNIX has no folders)?

Comment: It seems like you might be able to achieve what you're trying to do using `find .. -exec "command"`. As a general point, you should be using `$(command)` rather than backticks **`**, as the latter syntax is deprecated.

Comment: My thinking was that awk could parse out only the sections of the dirname that I was after and place them into the var $new_name, then use var $new_name to rename the file Anytest.drec with the underscores in place.  It didn't work and I don't know how to fix it.  As for folders and directories, I'm new to linux and am trying to learn it as I go.  Sorry for the misuse of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out what it is you're trying to do so let's first cleanup the syntax of your script and then see if it does what you want and if not you can tell us what's wrong.

Try this:

```
echo "Please enter the Master directory you wish to search or update"
read dir
jade_files=$(find /home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/"$dir" -name '*.drec' -print)

while IFS= read -r line; do   
    path=$(dirname "$line")
    ext="${line##*.}"
    basename=$(basename "$line")  
    new_name=$(echo "$basename" | awk '{print $5, "_", $6, "_", $7 }')
    echo "$new_name"
    cp -b /home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/Source_Files/"${new_name}.${ext}" "$line"
done <<< "$jade_files"
```

The setting of new_name in particular is very much just a guess that that's what you were trying to do.

Does the above do what you want? If not, what needs to be done differently?

Comment: Perhaps I can say this in a different way that will help you see what it is that I'm trying to do.  I have a file that I alter the contents of from time to time.  That's my source file and it's located in path1.    I want to take that file and copy it into the path V01A1A02 (and many more like it) with the sub directories /S00, or S01, etc.  Each of those (Sxx sub dir) have R00, R01, R02, etc as sub dir.  Each of those have a sub dir named /JADE.  The Anytest.drec file needs to reside there.  However, I want to change the name of the the /JADE/Anytest.drec file to include the path name

Comment: That path is actually /home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/V01A1A02/S00/R00/JADE/Anytest.drec  It's the 5th, 6th, and 7th positions of the path that I want to include in the new_name so that I can rename the /JADE/Anytest.drec file to now be /Jade/V01_A1_A02_S00_R00.drec.  My while loop with AWK is not working at all and that's where I needed help in figuring out how to parse out the dirname so that I could rename Anytest.drec.

Comment: Ed, when I tried your solution, I get the same result, cp: cannot stat ‘/home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/Source_Files/ _  _ .{drec}’: No such file or directory

Comment: `{$ext}` should have been `${ext}`, I've updated it now. I'm not surprised that's the result you get since it's unlikely your file name contains spaces and so `$5`, etc. from awk would be null strings. I still have no idea what you want, maybe due to my own laziness trying to follow the info you're providing but maybe you should come up with a simpler example/question that addresses just one of your requirements? e.g. `Given a variable with value XYZ how do I change it to ABC?`

Comment: #!/bin/bash -v

set -x

path1=/home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/Source_Files/Anytest.drec

echo "Please enter the Master directory you wish to search or update"

read dir

jade_files=$(find /home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/"$dir" -name '*.drec' -print)

echo "$jade_files"

while IFS= read -r line; do   
      path=$(dirname "$line")
      ext="${line##*.}"
      basename=$(basename "$line")  
      new_name=$(echo "$path" | awk -F "/" '{print $6"_"$7"_"$8}')
    echo "$new_name"
   cp -b "$path1" "$path"/"${new_name}.$ext"
done <<< "$jade_files"

Comment: okay, this is the fix i ended up using, it doesn't put all the underscores but it puts in most.  I'll fix the rest as I learn more.  Thanks Ed:

        #!/bin/bash 
        path1=/home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/Source_Files/Anytest.drec
        set -x
        echo "Please enter the Master folder you wish to search or update"
        read "folder"
        jade_files=`find /home/mike/Desktop/Active_Test/$folder -name "*.drec" -print`
        path=`dirname "$jade_files"`
        ext=${jade_files##*.}
        basename=`basename "$jade_files"` 
        cp -b "$path1" "$jade_files"."$ext"